# React Native authentication with Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I'm working on an app where i want to authenticate user using email and password in Firebase. I have already enabled the email and password sign-in method in my Firebase console. While running the app i encountered a Type Error "_this.setState is not a function. Below is my code. Check it and guide me please. Thank you.

My App.js

```
import React from "react";
import FirebaseKeys from "./config";
import * as firebase from "firebase";

export default () => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState(true);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }, 2000);
  }, []);

  state = {
    loggedIn: null,
  };

  var firebaseConfig = FirebaseKeys;

  if (!firebase.apps.length) {
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  }

  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user) {
      this.setState({
        loggedIn: true,
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        loggedIn: false,
      });
    }
  });

  if (isLoading) {
    return <Loading />;
  }
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      {loggedIn ? <DrawerScreen /> : <AuthStackScreen />}
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

LogginScreen.js

```
import firebase from "firebase";

export const SignIn = ({ navigation }) => {
  state = {
    email: "",
    password: "",
    errorMessage: null,
  };
  handleLogin = () => {
    const { email, password } = this.state;

    firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .catch((error) => this.setState({ errorMessage: error.message }));
  };
  return (

      <View style={styles.form}>
        <View>
          <Text style={styles.inputTitle}>Email Address</Text>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.input}
            autoCapitalize="none"
            onChangeText={(email) => this.setState({ email })}
            value={this.state.email}
          ></TextInput>
        </View>

        <View style={{ marginTop: 32 }}>
          <Text style={styles.inputTitle}>Password</Text>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.input}
            secureTextEntry
            autoCapitalize="none"
            onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({ password })}
            value={this.state.password}
          ></TextInput>
        </View>
      </View>

      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={this.handleLogin}>
        <Text style={{ color: "#FFF", fontWeight: "500" }}>Sign in</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{ alignSelf: "center", marginTop: 32 }}
        onPress={() => navigation.push("SignUp")}
      >
        <Text style={{ color: "#414959", fontSize: 13 }}>
          New to SocialApp?{" "}
          <Text style={{ fontWeight: "500", color: "#E9446A" }}>Sign up</Text>
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your App component is functional component so not exist this.setState, you should use useState instead.

```
import React from "react";
import FirebaseKeys from "./config";
import * as firebase from "firebase";

export default () => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState(true);
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = React.useState(false);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }, 2000);
  }, []);

  state = {
    loggedIn: null,
  };

  var firebaseConfig = FirebaseKeys;

  if (!firebase.apps.length) {
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  }

  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user) {
      setLoggedIn(true)
    } else {
      setLoggedIn(false)
    }
  });

  if (isLoading) {
    return <Loading />;
  }
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      {loggedIn ? <DrawerScreen /> : <AuthStackScreen />}
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```